# Catch coin amount from coin machine on android or ios

Tags: android, c++, ios

might not be a direct programming language question, but...

Remember those old days computers in which you could a quarter or whatever coin and your computer would be enabled for a certain time? such as in the image...

Does anyone know a way how this can be connected to a tablet (ios or android, doesnt matter which) and track how much was chucked in?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about a tablet, but you can do it with a Raspberry Pi. Every time a coin is inserted, it will trip a sensor and close a circuit. Since the Raspberry Pi has GPIO pins, you can catch that in any reasonable language you choose.

You could then put Android on the Raspberry Pi and probably end up a whole lot cheaper than a tablet would cost.

I would say this question is off-topic for being too broad, however.

Comment: I know it more or less was... but i couldn't find a better place to ask this question, and you have at least put me in the right direction. So it was helpful, and I thank you for your answer. The Pi interface in between, could indeed be a could option, never thought of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect it to Android device using IOIO("Yo Yo board")
For further details please [click here](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/280). For example [watch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yn5rSUN1z1M) this.